# got error in langchain youtube loader it says KeyError: 'videoDetails', PytubeError: Exception while accessing title of https://youtube.com/watch?v=

Tags: pytube, langchain

Got error accessing YouTube video title using Pytube library in Python when loading a YouTube video with the langchain.document_loaders.YoutubeLoader module. KeyError is raised when accessing vid_info['videoDetails']['title'], which causes a PytubeError. Upgrading Pytube to the latest version did not resolve the issue.

## code

```
from langchain.document_loaders import YoutubeLoader
loader = YoutubeLoader.from_youtube_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsYGlZkevEg", add_video_info=True)
loader.load()
```

## error message

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File d:\.......\langchain\.venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py:341, in YouTube.title(self)
    340 try:
--> 341     self._title = self.vid_info['videoDetails']['title']
    342 except KeyError:
    343     # Check_availability will raise the correct exception in most cases
    344     #  if it doesn't, ask for a report.

KeyError: 'videoDetails'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PytubeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 loader.load()

File d:\......\Open AI\langchain\.venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\youtube.py:133, in YoutubeLoader.load(self)
    128 metadata = {"source": self.video_id}
    130 if self.add_video_info:
    131     # Get more video meta info
    132     # Such as title, description, thumbnail url, publish_date
--> 133     video_info = self._get_video_info()
    134     metadata.update(video_info)
    136 try:
...
    350         )
    351     )
    353 return self._title

PytubeError: Exception while accessing title of https://youtube.com/watch?v=QsYGlZkevEg. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/pytube/pytube
```

I tried installing latets pytube from github. but it didint fix the error

Comment: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1556

Answer (score 0):

it's because of Google which blocked old Youtube clients versions (eg. YouTube vanced not working anymore) so pytube can't acces videos anymore